# Strip all attributes from an html and only return the tag name using regex

Tags: ruby, regex

As the title says, how can I achieve the following in ruby using regex or some other ruby magic?

**Input**

```
<a href="#" class="css-class">Link</a>
<img src="image.jpg" />
```

**Desired Output**

```
a
img
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Parsing HTML/XML with regex is bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how regex matching is handled in ruby, but i'm pretty sure that you can retrieve *groups* out of the regex.

For your case the regex:

`<([^\s]*).*(</.*>|/>)`

should do the trick.

After using it on your inputstring there will be only the tag names in group #1 for every match.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Tomalak, but if you still want to go with the regex approach, you could use something like the following:

```
\<(?<tag>[^ ]+)[^\>/]*(\>[^\<]*</\k<tag>\>|/\>)
```

I tested it only with the C# regex engine, I hope it works for ruby, too.